# Change Bootstrap Carousel Animation Duration Using Cubic Bizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello People** I Work On Change Bootstrap Slides Animation Direction and I Tried To Change My Bootstrap Carousel Slides Animation But There Are Some Problems:

```css
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    /*default Of Bootstrap Left: 0*/
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    top: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active {
  top: 0;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next,
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev {
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next.left,
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
/*Animation Cubic Bizer*/

#my-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.24,1.01,.3,.53);
  transition: 4s ease-in-out top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="40000" data-duration="3000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img alt="First slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717954391.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Second slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717968642.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 2</h3>
        <p>Morbi eget libero quis metus consectetur semper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Third slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717985113.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 3</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse ullamcorper massa eget eleifend iaculis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Note:** Please Run Code Snippet In Full Screen

Comment: What are the problems?

Comment: Run The Code And You Will See That No Transitions Between Slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove **this code:**

```
transition: 4s ease-in-out top;
```

and make item like this:

```
#my-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {

            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
            transition: 4s ease-in-out top;
        }
```

Also you need to change `carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION`:

First you must get data-duration value using jQuery `data()` function:

```
var itemDurVal = $(".carousel").data("duration"); 
/*get data-duration value of my carousel */
```

Then you can change slides animation:

That synchronize transition and **prevent** slide to disappear before transition ends.

```
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = itemDurVal;
```

And `.item` `transition-duration` value must equal `carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION` value:

```
$(".carousel-inner .item").css({
            '-webkit-transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms',
            '-moz-transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms',
            'transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms'
            });
```

Full code is here:

```js
var itemDurVal = $(".carousel").data("duration"); /*get data-duration value of my carousel */
        $.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = itemDurVal;
  $(".carousel-inner .item").css({
  '-webkit-transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms',
  '-moz-transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms',
  'transition-duration': itemDurVal + 'ms'
  });
```

```css
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    /*default Of Bootstrap Left: 0*/
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    top: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  #my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active {
  top: 0;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next,
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev {
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .next.left,
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
}
#my-carousel > .carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
/*Animation Cubic Bizer*/

#my-carousel .carousel-inner > .item {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.24,1.01,.3,.53);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="40000" data-duration="3000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img alt="First slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717954391.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Second slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717968642.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 2</h3>
        <p>Morbi eget libero quis metus consectetur semper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Third slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717985113.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 3</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse ullamcorper massa eget eleifend iaculis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete the CSS? You will get the CSS from bootstrap automatically. 
If you want to override Bootstraps CSS try to put `!important` after the line in CSS.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="40000" data-duration="3000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img alt="First slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717954391.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Second slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717968642.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 2</h3>
        <p>Morbi eget libero quis metus consectetur semper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Third slide" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-01/148549717985113.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption heading 3</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse ullamcorper massa eget eleifend iaculis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, But I'd Like Animations Depend On cubic-bezier Animations, Again Thank you For Helping Me

Comment: Could You Help Me Please